# Different ways to inherit objects in JavaScript with .call()

Tags: javascript

I was reading up on the [MDN example for .call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and tested the following code in my Chrome console:

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;

  if (price < 0) {
    throw RangeError('Cannot create product ' +
                      this.name + ' with a negative price');
  }

  return this;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);

var cheese = new Food('feta', 5); // Food {name: "feta", price: 5, category: "food"}
```

After playing around with it, I found out that either removing `Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);` or changing it to `Food.prototype = Product.prototype;` works just as well and returns the same results.

**Question** : What is the difference between calling:

1) `Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);`

2) `Food.prototype = Product.prototype;`

3) Removing `Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);` entirely

Comment: It inherits prototype methods, but you have no methods, so it won't make a difference, other than `Food` won't be a `Product`, it won't create a prototype chain.

Comment: Doing `Food.prototype = Product.prototype` will have very bad side effect. If you add any prototype property in `Food` (subclass), it will affect `Product` (superclass) which is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);`

Your Food prototype will be a copy of the Product's one. This is the correct way.

2. `Food.prototype = Product.prototype;`

Your Food prototype will be linked to your Product prototype: each thing you will do on the Food prototype, like an additional function, will be given to the Product as well.

Take the following instance:

```
Food.prototype = Product.prototype;

Food.prototype.eat = function () {
    console.log("num num num");
};

Product test = new Product("toto", 42);

test.eat(); // This will output "num num num", this shouldn't.
```

3. `Removing Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype); entirely`

There won't be inheritance, you won't be able to call Product functions on your Food. However, if you still make `Product.call` on your Food constructor, each attribute you set on the constructor  (like name and price in your example) will be set as well. Only methods won't be set.

```
Product = function (name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
};

Product.prototype.describe = function () {
    console.log(this.name + " : " + this.price);
};

Food = function (name, price) {
   Product.call(this, name, price);
};

var cheese = new Food("cheese", 5);

console.log(cheese.name); // Will work, because name was set in constructor.
cheese.describe(); // Won't work, because you didn't copy prototypes.
```